# Matrix class definition

Tags: python

I need some help especially for b). Thank you

Define a class for matrices as follows:
(a) Provide an implementation of `__init__` that takes a list of lists as input
and returns a new object of type matrix.

For the matrix A =

```
1 2
3 4
```

a user could enter `A = matrix( [[1,2],[3,4]])`.

(b) Provide an implementation of `__repr__` that returns a string representation of a matrix, printing each row in a separate line, e.g. printing A
as:

```
1, 2
3, 4
```

Comment: The author of this task hasn't quite grasped all the details of python: the return value of `__init__` is ignored, so asking to return anything from `__init__` is pointless. It is the `__new__` method that creates the object, calls its `__init__` method, discards the return value and returns the initialized object. If you know him, tell him. :)

Comment: Also, class names usually are capitalized, so that class would be called `Matrix`, not `matrix`; finally if I really wanted to nitpick, matrix prettyprinting is what I might expect from a `__str__` method, not a `__repr__` method. :)

Answer (score 6):

For a), it really depends on how you want to store the matrix. Storing the matrix as a list of lists, as is, is probably fine for most uses, but I don't know what *your* use is exactly. Matrixes have constraints that lists of lists lack (all rows have the same numbers of items of the same type); it will be up to this class to make sure that the restraints hold true. That said, if this is the entirety of the assignment, just using the list of lists as is will be okay.

Thus, you might want to make some doublechecking on the input. The [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) method will come in handy.

Here's what your constructor needs to be able to handle, eventually using Exceptions:

- `Matrix([])`
- `Matrix("Hi")`
- `Matrix([1])`
- `Matrix([1], [2])`
- `Matrix([1], [2, 3])`
- `Matrix([1,2], [3, 4])`
- `Matrix([1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0])`
- `Matrix([1.0 + 2j, 3.0 - 4j], [5.0 + 6.0j, 7.0 + 8.0j])`
- `a = []; a = [a, a]; Matrix(a)`

For b), well, all you need to do is put a `", "` between every row element and a `"\n"` between every row. [If only there was an easy way to do that...](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 3):

```
class matrix(object):
   def __init__(self,matrix)
      self.matrix = matrix

   def __repr__(self):
      return '\n'.join(','.join(str(m) for m in n) for n in self.matrix)
```

Since this is homework, I strongly recommend you to look up everything you don't know in the docs and to play around with it.

Comment: The `__repr__` doesn't match the requested format, not that you should be doing OP's homework for them.

Comment: This won't work for integers, also there is no need for the generator in the second join: return '\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrix])

Comment: fixed the string stuff and added note on what you should do with homework.